# Why is the inner Meta class of a Django model restricted?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a good reason why you can't add custom attributes to the inner Meta class of a Django model? The only one i can think of is to catch misconfigurations.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088431/adding-attributes-into-django-models-meta-class) shows how it can be worked around, but i'm wondering if there are any other reasons for this restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Options`, the class that processes `Meta`, and actually adds the `_meta` attribute to the model, runs through the attributes of `Meta` in a loop and uses `setattr` on itself to transfer the data. That process would fail if there's an attribute on `Meta` that doesn't exist on `Options`.

Now, there might be other reasons, but that's the only one I can glean from the source.